# WithTiming/WithSpring having jitters

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am making a bottom sheet in react-native with the help of react-native-reanimated2 and react-native-Gesture-handler. But when I use withTiming or withSpring it makes the Animated.view jump up and down a tiny bit. Any configurations I should make to make it stop having a "laggy" effect?

```
const scrollTo = useCallback((destination) => {
    'worklet';
    // translateY.value = destination
    translateY.value = withTiming(destination, { damping: 50, mass:0.5, })

  }, []);
```

Which is used in another component. and that component acts weird when withSpring or withTiming is used. but not when just dragging.

```
const rBottomSheetStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        const height = interpolate(
            translateY.value + 75,
            [0, MAX_TRANSLATE_Y],
            [0, -MAX_TRANSLATE_Y],
        );
        
        return {
            height,
        };
    })
```

[scrollTo not triggered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTdmp.png)

[scrollto on the way to top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1YVH.png)